# Emacs: Define a function which loads the file where the function itself is defined

Tags: emacs

I'm refactoring a bit in my Emacs set up and have come to the conclusion that I want to use a different init file than the default one.  So basically, in my ~/.emacs file, I have this:

```
(load "/some/directory/init.el")
```

Up until now, that's been working just fine. However, now I want to redefine an old command that I've used for ages, which opens my init file:

```
(defun conf ()
  "Open a buffer with the user init file."
  (interactive)
  (find-file user-init-file))
```

As you can see, this will open ~/.emacs no matter what I do. I want it to open /some/directory/init.el, or wherever the `conf` command itself is defined.

How would I do that?

Comment: @RandyMorris: No, I can't use only load-file-name, because it will be `nil` at the time of execution.

Comment: I found out that I can use `(symbol-file 'conf)` for this.

Comment: I realized that immediately after I posted that comment, my bad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `find-function` for this:

```
(defun conf ()
  "Open a buffer with the user init file."
  (interactive)
  (find-function this-command))
```

Comment: add the line "(beginning-of-buffer)" before the last parenthesis to start at the beginning of the buffer instead of that command.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use a sneakier way:

```
(defun conf () "blabla" (interactive) (find-file #$))
```

Because #$ works a bit like _*FILE*_ in C: it's replaced by the filename when the file is read.

Comment: This is very cool, but how would I have found out about it in Emacs's own documentation?  Even an explicit `(apropos "#$")` tells me nothing.

Comment: Well, I did say "sneakier".  I don't think this is (or should be) documented.  It's used internally in the format of .elc files and the .el and .elc files are actually processed in the same way, so this trick also works in .el files.

Comment: I guess a slightly less nasty way of doing this is `(symbol-function 'something 'defun)`?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
;;; mymodule.el --- does my thing

(defvar mymodule--load-path nil  "load path of the module")

   ...

(defun mymodule-load-datafile () 
  "load a data file from the directory in which the .el resides"
  (let* ((dir-name (concat
                        (file-name-directory mymodule--load-path)))
         (data-file-name (concat dir-name "datafile.csv")))
    (if (file-exists-p  data-file-name) 
         ... )))

;; remember load time path
(setq mymodule--load-path load-file-name)

(provide 'mymodule)
```